# Is it possible to connect the stdout of a child process to the stdout of the parent in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, console, output

So, I have the following code:

```
var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
{
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
    FileName = ToolPath
});
var stdOutputString = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
var stdErrorString = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
if (stdOutputString.Length > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(stdOutputString);
}
if (stdErrorString.Length > 0)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine(stdErrorString);
}
if (process.ExitCode != 0)
{
    throw new ToolException(process.ExitCode);
}
```

My problem with this code is that the stdout of the child process is not really connected to the stdout of the parent. Instead it becomes available only when the child process is over. Also, the child stdout may interleave with its stderr, but this code outputs all of the child stdout first and then all of its stderr.

I am looking for something like setting a pipe that would directly output on the parent's console the child's stdout and stderr.